# download file adds trailing blank lines

Tags: php, csv, download

In my current **laravel** project I am trying to **download a csv file** from a specific location

Everything is fine but the downloaded file has **two additional blank lines at the starting**

Instead of csv i have tested with text file also.The result is same.

I have also tried **plain php file download** it also does the same.

Need some urgemt suggestion

```
$file = public_path()."/Salesdata.csv"; 

return Response::download($file,"new.csv");
```

Comment: Update your question to include the code where you generate the file. Most likely that's where the issue is.

Comment: How about including a screenshot of the start of the Salesdata.csv file, too?

Comment: so the salesdata.csv or any other text file is created manually. So just think about a plain text file with one line string. but when i download it using response two additional trailing lines are added.I also tried the header thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blank lines before and after php tag was the reason for this additional lines in csv.

Answer (score -1):

<del>Try it like this. Trim is supposed to remove trailing space at the start and at the end of a variable.</del>

```
$file = public_path()."/Salesdata.csv";

return trim(Response::download($file,"new.csv"));
```

As @Alex_Andrei said, this will also trim the headers and everything returned by Reponse::download. You could try this, this might be a problem with the headers.

```
$headers = array('Content-Type: application/csv');
$file = public_path()."/Salesdata.csv";
return Response::download($file,"new.csv",$headers);
```

Comment: won't this trim the actual response, including headers and all, while leaving the contents of the `csv` intact?

Comment: True .. I'm gonna edit my answer, I think this might be a problem with the headers.

Comment: it's all assumptions until we know for sure that the lines aren't written in the csv itself

Comment: I agree ! And thanks for pointing out the fact that trim will actually trim everything returned by Reponse::download

Comment: trim is not gonna do anything because the original file is correct as its manually created..I also tried the header thing but it does not have any effect there. So just a simple thing that wanna download file from a location and the file is being downloaded with blank trailing lines. :(